# I would like to pass a parameter from the view to the controller in Rails 5

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, html-select

I have three models. 
- Client
- Idea
- employee
The client can have many ideas and the employee is the one who will take care of him. On the index page, I have a table in which you can select the client and enter the idea for them. But I'd like to have a dropdown with employees who are entering the data. The problem is that I do not know how to easily send this extra parameter.

So:

1. dropdown select employee
2. click on a link in the table for entering the idea for the client
3. send params of employee id and client id
4. save a new entry

How could I pass the extra parameter trough the link to? When I click on the "link to", I do get the client_id parameter. Do I have to make extra routes? Would I have to use javascript for this to edit the href in the table dynamically?

I have tried making a form with a get action but it did not work, the parameter did not go through.

```rb
# ideas controller
  def myaction
    @emp = params[:employee_id]
  end

# view
<%= form_tag(controller: "ideas", action: "myaction", method: "get") do %>
  <p>Who is your employee?</p>
  <%= select_tag "employee_id",options_for_select(@employees.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] } ) %>
<% end %>

this did not work, didnt get anything trough.
```

The Idea stores the client, employee and idea field.

Models:

```rb
class Idea < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  validates_presence_of :client
  validates_presence_of :idea
end


class client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ideas, dependent: :restrict_with_error

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
end

# controller for the idea
    def idea_params
      params.require(:idea).permit(:idea, :client_id,:employee_id) 
    end
# generating the table

  <tbody id="rubytabela">
    <% @clients.each do |client| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= client.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'enter idea',  new_idea_path(client_id: client ) %></td>   
        <td><%= client.id %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: To select and send a parameter like this, the easiest way would be to place it inside a form, and you could do it by customizing your `myaction` controller, to redirect you to the `new_idea_path` with the right parameters.

But I guess the simpler solution would be just adding your dropdown on the new idea form. Is it an option?

Comment: Hello, the idea would be that the dropdown does not redirect but just saves the selected value, so the `myaction` would only serve to save the value in the controller somehow. Sadly the dropdown should be in a view before the new idea, otherwise it would be easier to do.